# How to configure DNS on Server 2012 to allow hosts without "extension"?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

I'm using Windows Server 2012 as my DNS server. I'd like to have the address `http://intranet` to point to 192.168.0.180. I'm not able to reach this. If I create a Forward Lookup Zone, for example Local and add a host (A-record) there named "intranet", navigating to `http://intranet.local` goes to the right place.

What I want is to get rid of this .local extension. How can I achieve this? I had it working in Server 2008, but after reinstalling the system I can't remember how I had it done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not done on the DNS server. Rather, on your clients, set `.local` as one of their DNS search domains. This is typically set in your DHCP scope options.

Comment: Do you remember what option this is? People seem to use 119, but that's not an option for newer systems.

Comment: I don't, and unfortunately I don't have a 2012 DHCP server available to check at the moment.

Comment: Thanks anyway! I found the answer with Google. I had to set option 15 in my DHCP server options to contain the DNS suffix.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to EEAA's answer, which is perfectly fine, I would also like to add that another good way of accomplishing this would be to implement a GlobalNames zone on your DNS servers.

http://www.petri.co.il/using-globalnames-zone-window-server-2008.htm